# Ruby file locations and requiring them

Tags: ruby

I am trying to require:

```
PROJECT_DIR/lib/shrt.rb
```

from:

```
PROJECT_DIR/test/shrt_test.rb
```

I tried:

```
require File.expand_path('.././lib/shrt.rb')
# and
require './lib/shrt.rb'
# and
require_relative '../lib/shrt.rb'
```

However it gives me an error stating it cannot load a file that is required in the `shrt.rb` file in `lib/`. In `PROJECT_DIR/`, I ran via Rake a Ruby test file:

```
ruby 'test/shrt_test.rb'
```

Any idea what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to require the files in the following way:

```
require './lib/shrt/version'
require './lib/shrt/client'
```

...in the file I was trying to require in the test file. I required that file using `require_relative '../lib/shrt'`.

**EDIT** However now, when I `rake install` the gem, I'm using Bundler, and run it, I get `` `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib/shrt/version (LoadError) ``.

**EDIT 2** Fixed the problem by `require_relative` instead of just `require` on the `version` file.

Answer (score 0):

Does:

```
require './lib/shrt.rb'
```

Not work? I've always required files in projects that way.

Comment: The extension is not necessary. Ruby automatically adds it.

Comment: Good catch. I was more concerned with sharing the path and less concerned with the extension being there. :)

Comment: No, when I put that code in the test file, and run it via Rake I get this error `cannot load such file -- ./shrt/version (LoadError)`. That `version.rb` file is required in the file I'm trying to require in `lib/shrt.rb`.